# Creating data entry form on the fly with PHP and MySql keeps crashing browser

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am having an issue with this website I am designing and am reaching for help before I rip my eyes out.  The expected result of the following script is a web page with an input form that should look like the following (With

```
James Craig | Week 7 | <INPUT>max</INPUT | <INPUT>ctrl</INPUT>
Jo Mama   | Week 7 | <INPUT>max</INPUT | <INPUT>ctrl</INPUT>
```

However, All I actually see is:

```
James Craig Week 7 max: ctrl:
```

No text input fields, and no table formatting.  Also, it does not show the second person.

Then:  Page locks up and crashes the browser.

I suspect my loops are not ending, but I am beyond lost at this point.  I know it is a lot to ask, but can someone straighten me out here? :)

Basic data that I am working with:

Database sample data

```
Table Name: loginUsers
--------------------------------------------------------
|      storeID      |      login     |    password     |
|-------------------|----------------|-----------------|
|       0460        |    store0460   |    store0460    |
--------------------------------------------------------

Table Name: specialistData
--------------------------------------------------------
|    specialistID   |    week    |     max    | ctrl   |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|         1         |      1     |    28.50   |  19.99 |
|         1         |      2     |    17.85   |  21.99 |
|         1         |      3     |    16.99   |  99.99 |
|         1         |      4     |    28.50   |  19.99 |
|         1         |      5     |    28.50   |  19.99 |
|         1         |      6     |    28.50   |  19.99 |
|         2         |      1     |    28.50   |  19.99 |
|         2         |      2     |    17.85   |  21.99 |
|         2         |      3     |    16.99   |  99.99 |
|         2         |      4     |    28.50   |  19.99 | 
|         2         |      5     |    28.50   |  19.99 |
|         2         |      6     |    28.50   |  19.99 |
--------------------------------------------------------    
Table Name: usersSpecialists
--------------------------------------------------------
|      storeID      |  specialistID  |       name      |
|-------------------|----------------|-----------------|
|       0460        |        1       |    James Craig  |
|       0460        |        2       |     Jo Mama     |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

PHP document in question (I removed DB Connection strings, but I assure you they work fine)

```
<?php

//Initialize the session
session_start();

//Check for existing session.  Route to login if not
if(!isset( $_SESSION['username'])){
header('Location: ../index.php');
}
?>

<?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/functions.php"); ?>




<html>
<head>
    <title>Weekly Data</title>
    <link href="portal.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

        <div id="masthead">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                <li class = "active"><a href="#">View Report</a></li>
                <li class = "active"><a href="#">Edit Specialists</a></li>
                <li class = "active"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
            <h3 class="muted">Sales Specialist Ranker - Weekly Data</h3>
        </div>

<hr>

<div id="jumbotron"><center>
            <h1>Enter Weekly Data</h1>
            <form action="submitData.php method="GET">

            </form>



            <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="#">Submit</a>        
</center></div>
<?php 

//This will determine the current week, compare it to the last entry for each specialist, and create a form to request any needed data.

//Obtain currently logged in store (Store Number)
    $currentStore = $_SESSION['username'];

//Obtain Current Week
    $currentWeek = date("W"); 

//Obtain list of specialists (specialist ID)
    //Create temp mysqli object
    $specialistList = new mysqli();

    //Grab specialist list
    $specialistList = getSpecialists($currentStore);

//Loop through each specialist and generate form

    //Start Form
    echo "<form name='specialistData' action='submitData.php' method='get'>";
    //Start Loop
        while($row = $specialistList->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

            //Start HTML Table
            echo "<table class='dataEntry'>";

            //create temp mysqli object
            $lastWeek = new mysqli();

            //Get last entry for specialist
            $lastWeekData = lastEntry($row['specialistID']);
            $lastWeekData = $lastWeekData->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $lastWeek = $lastWeekData['week'];
            $specialistID = $row['specialistID'];
            $specialistName = $lastWeekData['name'];

            //compare last week to current week

                //Begin loop
                while($lastWeek < $currentWeek){

                    //create HTML Input for each specialist
                    echo    "<tr>\n
                                <td>$specialistName</td>\n
                                <td>Week: $lastWeek</td>\n
                                <td>Max: <input type='text' name='".$specialistID."-".$lastWeek."-max /></td>\n
                                <td>Max: <input type='text' name='".$specialistID."-".$lastWeek."-ctrl /></td>\n
                            </tr>\n";

                    $lastweek++;
                }

            //Close HTML table for this specialist
            echo "</table>";
        }

        //Close HTML Form
        echo "</form>";

?>

<hr>
<div class="footer">
    <p> Footer Here</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my functions.php

```
<?php //FUNCTIONS
function getSpecialists($user){ 
/*
        PURPOSE:   GET LIST OF SPECIALISTS THAT BELONG TO CURRENT USER
        ARGUMENTS: $user{USER ID - STRING}
        RETURN:    MYSQLI OBJECT CONTAINING RESULT LIST {specialistID}
*/

//Include DB Strings
$DB_HOST = "****";
$DB_NAME = "****";
$DB_USER = "****";
$DB_PASS = "****";

    //Query create the SQL object
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
    //Plan for error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n". mysqli_connect_error(error)." \n WHEN: OBTAINING SPECIALIST LIST");
        exit();
    }

    //Create QUERY to return {specialistID}
    $sql = "SELECT      usersSpecialists.specialistID
            FROM        usersSpecialists
            INNER JOIN  loginUsers
            ON          usersSpecialists.storeID = loginUsers.storeID
            WHERE       loginUsers.login = '$user'";


    //Launch the query
    $specialistResults = $mysqli->query($sql);

    //Send back results of query
    return $specialistResults;  
}



function lastEntry($specialist){
/*
        PURPOSE:   GET THE LATEST ENTRY (WEEK NUMBER) FOR GIVEN SPECIALIST
        ARGUMENTS: $specialistID{SPECIALIST IN QUESTION - INT}
        RETURN:    MYSQLI OBJECT CONTAINING RESULT LIST {week, name}
*/
//Include DB connection strings
$DB_HOST = "****";
$DB_NAME = "****";
$DB_USER = "****";
$DB_PASS = "****!";

    //Query create the SQL object
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
    //Plan for error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n". mysqli_connect_error(error)." \n WHEN: OBTAINING SPECIALIST LIST");
        exit();
    }

    //Create SQL query
    $sql = "SELECT      specialistData.week, usersSpecialists.name
            FROM        specialistData
            INNER JOIN  usersSpecialists
            ON          specialistData.specialistID = usersSpecialists.specialistID
            WHERE       specialistData.specialistID = $specialist
            ORDER BY    specialistData.week DESC
            LIMIT       1";

    //Launch SQL query
    $lastWeek = $mysqli->query($sql);

    //Return mysqli result $lastWeek {week, name}
    return $lastWeek;
}




?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but not enough code provided. You have to post at least 2 times more, to make question answerable.

Comment: use limit i think your data is large

Comment: lol Sorry, I just thought I would provide all info that I thought was relevent....

Comment: Nanhe: In which query?  I have tested viable queries in both and they yield only the expected number of rows.  In the first, $user is unique and in the second, I did use LIMIT... Thanks for fast reply though :)

Comment: I don't understand the code in `while($lastWeek < $currentWeek)` loop you are printing the same thing several times.

Comment: It should ++ $lastweek until it matches $current week, therefore creating a new entry row for each missing week number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a solution.  The problem was being caused by looping queries.  Apparently this overloaded everything.  I went back to square one and:

1) Created a new query that got ALL my needed info at once via JOINS

2) Rewrote my PHP so it looped the returned data with no further need to call mysqli->query

Here is the revised code:

```
<?php

//Initialize the session
session_start();

//Check for existing session.  Route to login if not
if(!isset( $_SESSION['username'])){
header('Location: ../index.php');
}
?>





<?php  //This will determine the last week entered for each specialist and generate an entry form for all missing data

//Obtain currently logged in store (Store Number)
    $currentStore = $_SESSION['username'];

//Obtain Current Week
    $currentWeek = date("W"); 

//Include DB Strings
$DB_HOST = "****";
$DB_NAME = "****";
$DB_USER = "****";
$DB_PASS = "****";

//Query create the SQL object
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
//Plan for error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n". mysqli_connect_error(error));
        exit();
    }

//Create QUERY to return {specialistID}
    $sql = "SELECT      usersSpecialists.specialistID, 
                        usersSpecialists.name, 
                        max(specialistData.week)
            FROM        loginUsers
            INNER JOIN  usersSpecialists    
            ON          loginUsers.storeID = usersSpecialists.storeID
            INNER JOIN  specialistData      
            ON          usersSpecialists.specialistID = specialistData.specialistID
            WHERE       loginUsers.login = '$currentStore'
            GROUP BY    usersSpecialists.specialistID, usersSpecialists.name";

//Launch query
    $results = $mysqli->query($sql);

//Get current week
    $currentWeek = date("W");  

//Loop through each specialist and generate form

    //Start Form
    echo "<form name='specialistData' action='submitData.php' method='get'>";

    //Start Loop
        while($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

            //Create visually friendly variables
            $name = $row['name'];
            $id = $row['specialistID'];
            $week = $row['max(specialistData.week)']; 

            //++ is there to negate the week that is already entered (The last week we have)
            $week++;

            //Check if data is current
            if($week < $currentWeek){

                //Start Table for unique specialist
                echo "<table><th>Name</th><th>Week</th><th>Max</th><th></th>";

                //Loop until week matches for data entry
                while($week < $currentWeek){

                    //Create entries for each needed week
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>$name</td>
                            <td>$week</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='max" . $id . $week . "'></td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='ctrl" . $id . $week . "'></td>
                          </tr>";

                        //Increment $week
                        $week++;
                }
            } else {
                echo "<p>No data needed for ". $name . ".";
            }
        }

?>
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Always use a full qualified absolute url for redirects. `header('Location: http://your.site.com/index.php');`